# does the email-validator python library send out actual emails to check deliverability?

Tags: python, email-validation

Has anyone used the python library [[https://pypi.org/project/email-validator/]](https://pypi.org/project/email-validator/)
it has a check_deliverability=True option. Does this option send out actual emails to check deliverability? I only want to check if it looks like a valid email address and do not want to actually send out any emails.

The documentation mentions: check_deliverability=True: If true, DNS queries are made to check that the domain name in the email address (the part after the @-sign) can receive mail, as described above.

I am just trying to make sure it does not before testing it on a huge number of emails.

Thank you.

I did try to validate a few personal emails using this library and no email was received on those.But just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Test it on a single email address -- yours.

Comment: yes I did check it with my own and a few others and it did not send any email. Just making sure before using it on a huge list of emails.

Comment: I haven't looked at the code but "DNS queries" sounds as if the existence of an MX record is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. It would be highly impractical if it would.

https://github.com/JoshData/python-email-validator/blob/main/email_validator/deliverability.py